# How to return multiple dictionaries from my Python main function

Tags: python, function, methods, dictionary

I have a main function that contains two dictionaries that I would like to output.  I have omitted how the dictionaries were created.

here's my function:

```
def main()
    dict1 = {'a1':{'b1':1,'c1':2},'a2':{'b2':1,'c2':2}}
    dict2 = {'cat':0,'dog':2}
    return dict1, dict2
if __main__ == '__main__':
>...main()
```

here's how I'm calling it in the python prompt:

```
>>from filename import *
>>x,y=main()
```

More or less this is what I'm getting

```
>>print x
'a1'
>>print y
'a2'
```

But this is what I want:

```
>>print x
{'a1':{'b1':1,'c1':2},'a2':{'b2':1,'c2':2}}
>>print y
{'cat':0,'dog':2}
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: I copied your code in my compiler, and it works just fine...

Comment: You're not showing the actual code. Please don't post something that you did not test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code already does exactly what you expect it to:

```
In [4]: def main():
   ...:     dict1 = {'a1':{'b1':1,'c1':2},'a2':{'b2':1,'c2':2}}
   ...:     dict2 = {'cat':0,'dog':2}
   ...:     return dict1, dict2
   ...: 

In [5]: x, y = main()

In [6]: x
Out[6]: {'a1': {'b1': 1, 'c1': 2}, 'a2': {'b2': 1, 'c2': 2}}

In [7]: y
Out[7]: {'cat': 0, 'dog': 2}
```

Perhaps you're accidentally calling a different `main()` function (e.g. one that has a different `return` statement)?

Answer (score 2):

You're not `return`ing `dict1, dict2`, just `dict1`. You can easily reproduce this behavior:

```
>>> dict1 = {'a1': 'some_stuff', 'a2': 'some_other_stuff'}
>>> dict2 = {'cat': 0, 'dog': 0}
>>> return_val = dict1
>>> x, y = return_val
>>> x
'a1'
>>> y
'a2'
>>> return_val = dict1, dict2
>>> x, y = return_val
>>> x
{'a1': 'some_stuff', 'a2': 'some_other_stuff'}
>>> y
{'cat': 0, 'dog': 0}
```

This happens because when you iterate over a dictionary you get its keys, so when you do `x, y = main()` and `main` returns `dict1`, you iterate over the keys of `dict1`. Since there happen to be two of them, you don't get an error and `x` and `y` take the value of those keys.

If you change `main` to return both dictionaries, you should be fine.

Comment: The code he *posted* returns the two dictionaries, so it should be fine.  The code he is *executing* doesn't.

Comment: @cvoinescu Yes, the code he posted is fine. But it is obviously not his real code, so it's not what I address in my answer. It would be nice if people asking questions didn't make that kind of error, but at least in this case the real problem is clear.

Comment: Maybe he's executing old code because he doesn't know how to reload the module (`reload(filename)`) to apply the changes he made to filename.py?

Comment: @cvoinescu There are lots of reasons it could be. He could have more than one `filename.py`, he could need to restart his interpreter, etc. But the reason he gets the output he does is that the code he's running is returning only one dictionary.